# How do I say "black people" respectfully in Esperanto?

Tags: word-usage, single-word-requests

According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#negro), *negro* and *nigrulo* are synonymous meaning a person from the black race. However, they sound derogative to my Scandinavian ears.

Are they? Is there a less offensive word?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a danger in importing sensitivities from our national cultures because in cases like this, sensitivity varies so much. I think *nigrulo* is fine - and if it's not fine, I would hope that people who come to Esperanto would cut me a little slack for saying it.

It seems to me a more important question is whether it's important in any given situation to even mention race. In some cases it may be - and I'd say *blankulo*, *nigrulo*, etc.. I suppose you could also say *afrik-devena*.

Comment: Your answer does not say anything about *negro*, which the question also asks about.

Comment: "There is a danger in importing sensitivities from our national cultures because in cases like this, sensitivity varies so much." --

i think the same applies to "negro". "nigrulo" sounds just as offensive to an american as negro, but it doesn't mean it's offensive in Esperanto. "farti" sounds like juvenile joke to us too, but it doesn't mean it is in Esperanto.

Comment: I refer indirectly to "negro" under "importing sensitivities." Use it if you must. Don't freak out if others do and you do not. I don't have a strong opinion on it either way. I didn't mention it explicitly because my personal preference is for "nigrulo" - which corresponds to blankulo. Since there's no white version of "negro", I find it to be unnecessary ballast at best.

Answer (score 13):

The common word nowadays is *nigrulo*. The word *negro* used to be the common word until a few decades ago, but nowadays many Esperantists consider it to have a slight negative connotation (comparable to the English *negro*, not to the English word *nigger*).

The word *nigrulo* literally means 'black person', and it is just as neutral and non-derogative a term as *black person* is in English.

Answer (score 8):

I do not think there is anything wrong with *nigrulo*, this is just a word for someone of the black race. In the same way, there is [*blankulo*](http://vortaro.net/#blankulo) in PIV, for people of the white race. Those are just colours with a person-suffix. They (in my opinion) do not carry the same baggage that English or any other language would put on them.

As some side info, I can add that in my native Bulgarian, the *N-word (негър)* is a perfectly normal word for a black-skinned person, that doesn't carry the same derrogative meaning that the English has. It is used on TV an everywhere. For that reason, I would avoid implying something from one language to another. And because of that, I would say that *negro* is also a normal word in Esperanto.

Comment: ”Blank-ulo” and ”nigr-ulo” both sound fine to me. I think the problem with the word Esperanto ”negro” is that it’s a separate word that marks Black people as ”the other”. Imagine if there only were the words ”nigrulo” and ”blenko” (instead of ”blankulo”). I’m sure many Whites would object to being called ”blenkoj”?

Comment: BTW, are there any Black Esperantists reading this? What do you think? Cetere, ĉu iuj nigraj Esperantistoj legas ĉi tion? Kion pensas vi?

Comment: @Bjørn Well, it's not like white and black are all there are; and other ethnic groups are not referred to by color (rugxulo? flavulo?), so why should Blacks and Whites be? Just because they're usually called that in English?

Comment: @kristan Okay, you have a point. :-) Of course, Esperanto does not need to copy English. Still, we need a way to talk about physical appearance – and that includes skin colour and hair texture, not just eye colour and hair colour. How would you say ”a white person” and ”a black person” in Esperanto?

Comment: I would say: They do not carry the same baggage, because it's not as much about what the words mean as about how they have been used and what connections have been made to them throughout history. Esperanto is lucky in that it is a new language and the history just happened elsewhere. So we have a chance to start afresh and do it right this time :-)

Comment: From my experience, nowadays the only people still actively using *negro* are white people who are not really sensitive for the issue of racial discrimination against black people. The last time I have seen it was in an article by an old Dutch Esperantist who defended the Dutch tradition of "Zwarte Piet", claiming it to not include any elements of racism (which seems to me to be a clearly false statement).

Comment: @kristan & Bjørn - It's not just English that's using the colors white and black to refer to those two races. I get the impression it's relatively universal. Japanese does it too, for example. (黒人 = black person, and 白人 = white person, which I'm pretty sure are the politically correct terms. Though they sounded a bit off to me at first.) Other races and ethnic groups don't have as international terms. I'm not sure East-Asians ever call themselves yellow, for example.

Comment: I use nigrulo, blankulo and flavulo if I need to refer to someone's skin without an issue. I rarely see negro used however I did recently see it used in a Esperanto video from Asia though you could tell there was no malice there.
Don't ask me for a link to the video as it was in my Facebook feed.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think the word in itself is problematic, I'll admit it sounds off to my western ears, but I don't think there's anything insidious there. I'm a black female esperantist -- yes a 'nigrulino' -- and I have had people tell me the language is "racist" and "sexist" because of certain words and the *-in* suffix. I however don't find it to be so.

In fact, what language isn't racist or sexist on some levels, and would that be because us humans are indeed racist and sexist. The good thing about Esperanto is that, I think, it tries to put people on equal footing, despite having been invented more than a century ago, in Eastern Europe, before the Holocaust when I'm sure tensions were rife, Esperanto  itself seems to have a pretty  noble cause. Now people...  that's another matter

Comment: Your answer does say anything about "negro", which the question is also about.

Comment: Marcos, the question is about both negro and nigrulo, and the answer is relevant to both words.

Answer (score 2):

Nigrulo literally means "Black person" so I think you are in the clear with that one

Comment: Your answer does say anything about "negro", which the question is also about.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this word **malhelhaŭtuloj**? 
I saw it in one dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Do uzu "estimatan nigrulon" ;)

Jes, tio estas sxerco. Serioze, en Esperanto simple uzu "nigrulon", tio ja estas la gxusta vorto.

Kial en la angla oni evitas la vorton "negro"-n? La vorto mem estis neuxtrala sed en historio tio vaste uzigxis de sklavoposedantoj, do la vorto kunportas maldolcxan memoron kaj malamon. Unu vorto, malgraux kiel bela gxi aspektas, se gxi kunportas malamon, estas ofenda vorto. Se ne, gxi tauxgas por egala komunikado.

Esperantujo ne havas tian trsitan memoron kaj kulpan kulturon, do oni nenecesas esti sentema pri tio.

Respondo de iu flavulo ;)

Answer (score -2):

It is not offensive for most Esperanto speakers because black is nothing more than a color.

However, for English speakers like me, it sounds terrible. Maybe you could say: **Li havas Afrik-koloron**.

Comment: No doubt most people would understand what you intend to say with **Li havas Afrik-koloron**… :-) But you should also expect a lot of language-focused Esperantists commenting things like **Sed kontinento ne havas koloron!** aŭ **Sed ankaŭ la blankaj sudafrikanoj kaj la brunaj (arabaj kaj berberaj) nordafrikanoj havas Afrik-koloron!** ;-)

Comment: I think it's a [quite universal term](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=africa+colour&tbm=isch) :-)

Comment: Well, most of those photos show multicoloured things like flags and African textiles. Hm, when was the last time I saw a human with green, yellow, red and black skin? :-P

Comment: You'll want to be careful saying "afrik-koloron" because a lot of "nigruloj" don't come from Africa and there is even a large population of "blankuloj" who do live in Africa.

Comment: @Evildea Yah. Maybe there is no good alternative.